# Dynamic php and jQuery click not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'd already been struggling with this as (after checking this site) I'd found I wasn't using `.on` to delegate a click function that is fired when clicking a piece of php dynamically generated html.

I've now added the `.on` but I'm still finding the item that needs clicking requires clicking twice the first time it is used.

```
$(document).on('click', '.drone', function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass( "unselected" )) {

    var partNumber = $(this).find("p").text();

    //Check if input fields are empty and fills if so
    if ($("#input-one").val().length == 0 ){
      $('input[type=text]#input-one').val(partNumber);

      //Add selected class to box
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $(this).removeClass('unselected');
    }
    else if ($("#input-two").val().length == 0 ){
      $('input[type=text]#input-two').val(partNumber);

      //Add selected class to box
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $(this).removeClass('unselected');
    }
  }
  else { 
    $(this).addClass('unselected');
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    var partNumber = $(this).find("p").text();
      //IF to check which input box to remove details from
    if (partNumber == $("#input-one").val()){
      $('input[type=text]#input-one').val("");
    }
    else if (partNumber == $("#input-two").val()){
      $('input[type=text]#input-two').val("");
    }
  }
});
```

Below is the php used to generate the content.

```
   <?php 
//Get products information
$brand_query = "SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN `WebProducts` on table.part_number = Products.stockcode ORDER by price DESC" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($db2));
$brand_result = mysqli_query($db2, $brand_query);

while($prod_row = mysqli_fetch_array($brand_result)){
$prod_display .= '
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="product drone">
                <div class="product-info">

                    <img class="product-image" src="http://www.sitename.co.uk/image.php?width=300&amp;filename=' . urlencode($prod_row['imgfilename']) . '" alt="'.$prod_row['description'].'" />
                    <p class="part">'.$prod_row['part_number'].'</p>
                    <h3 class="product-title">'.$prod_row['description'].'</h3>
                    <span class="product-price highlight">£'.$prod_row['price'].'</span>
                    <button class="mail-modal-btn btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="action-text">Add to Compare</span></button>

                    <a style="visibility:hidden" href="'.$home_page_link.'product/'.$prod_row['part_number'].'/'.url_slug($prod_row['description']).'"><button class="mail-modal-btn btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="action-text">View Details</span></button></a>
                </div>

</div></div>';
}

echo $prod_display;
?>
```

Comment: what is your problem now?

Comment: What should happen if you click on `.drone`?

Comment: You seem to be toggling classes on click, but is any of the classes there when the html is loaded?

Comment: Clicking on a product with the drone class should add or remove a new class. That works fine but...the items require being clicked twice rather than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not setting the class `unselected` when you first create it, so the `else` block fires, removing the `selected` class (which isn't there), and adding the `unselected` class for the first time. Hence a second click is required to fire the first `if` block of code.

Try this PHP code instead:

```
   <?php 
//Get products information
$brand_query = "SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN `WebProducts` on table.part_number = Products.stockcode ORDER by price DESC" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($db2));
$brand_result = mysqli_query($db2, $brand_query);

while($prod_row = mysqli_fetch_array($brand_result)){
$prod_display .= '
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="product drone unselected">
                <div class="product-info">

                    <img class="product-image" src="http://www.sitename.co.uk/image.php?width=300&amp;filename=' . urlencode($prod_row['imgfilename']) . '" alt="'.$prod_row['description'].'" />
                    <p class="part">'.$prod_row['part_number'].'</p>
                    <h3 class="product-title">'.$prod_row['description'].'</h3>
                    <span class="product-price highlight">£'.$prod_row['price'].'</span>
                    <button class="mail-modal-btn btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="action-text">Add to Compare</span></button>

                    <a style="visibility:hidden" href="'.$home_page_link.'product/'.$prod_row['part_number'].'/'.url_slug($prod_row['description']).'"><button class="mail-modal-btn btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="action-text">View Details</span></button></a>
                </div>

</div></div>';
}

echo $prod_display;
?>
```

The important part being:

```
<div class="product drone unselected">
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. Worked perfectly. I was so busy obsessing over the .on function I didn't even look if the php was wrong.

Comment: No problem, glad it's working for you. On a side note, I can't imagine an `unselected` class is necessary, unless there's a third state? Because you can just check for the presence of the `selected` class. May help clean up the jQuery code a bit.